# Diferença entre cast de estruturas

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct, cast

```
struct a{

   int a;
   int b;
};

struct b{

  int a;
  int b;

}

int main()
{

   struct a *p;

   struct b b;

  p = (struct a *)b; // deste modo da erro

  p = (struct a *)&b; ; deste modo o compilador não aponta erro;

}
```

Gostaria de saber o porquê?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o problema? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso. Você estaria ajudando a comunidade identificando a melhor solução. Só pode aceitar uma delas, mas pode votar em qualquer coisa no site todo.

Answer (score 2):

`(struct a *)b` está pegando uma estrutura e fazendo um *cast* para um **ponteiro para uma estrutura**. Isso não é possível. Um ponteiro é algo muito diferente de uma estrutura.

Nesse caso está tentando botar uma estrutura com dois inteiros dentro de um ponteiro e não cabe. O ponto principal do tipo `struct a *` é que ele é um ponteiro. Para o que ele aponta é importante, mas secundário, primariamente é um ponteiro.

`(struct a *)&b` está pegando um endereço para uma estrutura, que é um ponteiro e fazendo um *cast* para um **ponteiro para uma estrutura**, isso é possível. São tipos incompatíveis, é ponteiro para ponteiro.

O `&` é o operador que pega o endereço de algo, ou seja, ele gera um dado que potencialmente será um ponteiro, mas jamais será uma estrutura.